# Change position of content within webview - Electron/Chrome/JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, webview, electron

I've been working all day to sort this out and still no closer. I have a Electron app which loads multiple webviews. I am trying so that once one of the webviews fully loads the scroll position is moved 200px down the page.

[image: Example here....]

I would have thought I would have to user Jquery to do this however what I have below has no effect with no errors in the console. Any pointers would be great,

thanks

---

HTML

head

```
 <head>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

webview

```
<div class="demo">
<webview id="wv1" src="https://www.github.com/" style="display:inline-flex; height: 180px; width: 100%; "></webview>
</div>
```

jquery

```
<script>
$( "div.demo" ).scrollTop( 200 );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window.onload doesn't seem to work well with webviews. The event listener waits for the dom-ready event to inject the scroll instructions into the webview. This has to be done for every webview. A JS file could be injected with the preload attribute.

```
const webview = document.querySelector('#webviewId')
webview.addEventListener('dom-ready', () => {
  webview.executeJavaScript(
    'document.documentElement.scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop = 200;');
})
```

Comment: Still has no effect I'm afraid, I am guessing you meant put the above in a script thats called after the webview has loaded i.e. <script>
document.querySelector('#wv2').executeJavaScript(
'window.onload="document.documentElement.scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop = 200;"', false, function(){ console.log('callback'); });
</script>

Comment: The idea was to inject the JavaScript into the webview. The webview is therefore the window. Is there an error message in the console? Sorry for the speculation. Maybe document.querySelector('#webviewId').getWebContents().executeJavaScript('function(){ window.onload="document.documentElement.scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop = 200;"; }()')